# Show text as value Power Pivot using DAX formula

Tags: excel, dax

Is there a way by using a DAX measure to create the column which contain text values instead of the numeric sum/count that it will automatically give?

In the example below the first name will appear as a value (in the first table) instead of their name as in the second.

[image]

**Data table:**

```
+----+------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+
| id | first_name | last_name  |   currency    | Sales | Stock |
+----+------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+
|  1 | Giovanna   | Christon   | Peso          |    10 |    12 |
|  2 | Roderich   | MacMorland | Peso          |     8 |    10 |
|  3 | Bond       | Arkcoll    | Yuan Renminbi |     4 |     6 |
|  1 | Giovanna   | Christon   | Peso          |    11 |    13 |
|  2 | Roderich   | MacMorland | Peso          |     9 |    11 |
|  3 | Bond       | Arkcoll    | Yuan Renminbi |     5 |     7 |
|  1 | Giovanna   | Christon   | Peso          |    15 |    17 |
|  2 | Roderich   | MacMorland | Peso          |    10 |    12 |
|  3 | Bond       | Arkcoll    | Yuan Renminbi |     6 |     8 |
|  1 | Giovanna   | Christon   | Peso          |    17 |    19 |
|  2 | Roderich   | MacMorland | Peso          |    11 |    13 |
|  3 | Bond       | Arkcoll    | Yuan Renminbi |     7 |     9 |
+----+------------+------------+---------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Use CONCATENATEX: https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/july-2018-excel-reporting-text-in-a-pivot-table/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search I found 4 ways.

measure 1 (will return blank if values differ):

```
=IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Table1[first_name])) > 1, BLANK(), VALUES(Table1[first_name]))
```

measure 2 (will return blank if values differ):

```
=CALCULATE(
VALUES(Table1[first_name]),
FILTER(Table1,
COUNTROWS(VALUES(Table1[first_name]))=1))
```

measure 3 (will show every single text value), thanks @ Rory:

```
=CONCATENATEX(Table1,[first_name]," ")
```

For very large dataset this concatenate seems to work better:

```
=CALCULATE(CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Table1[first_name]),Table1[first_name]," "))
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Measure 1 can be simplified: IF(HASONEVALUE(Table1[first_name]), VALUES(Table1[first_name]))

Answer (score 2):

No DAX needed. You should put the `first_name` field on Rows and not on Values. Select `Tabular View` for the Report Layout. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Design -> Report Layout -> Show in Tabular Form. Could come handy some day.

Comment: Your welcome. But the main point of my answer was the first part. Put the `first_name` field on Rows and not on Values. Did that work for you?